# Assigning feature symbology by categories with related table in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, relationship-class, arcgis-collector

I am making maps for Collector app with features and related tables.

Is there a simple way to assign different symbol to features based on whether it has related records or not?

Comment: Finally I ended up with creating an extra field for feature class and creating trigger in database to update delta tables as we are using versioned db. Looking forward to seeing updates from ESRI.

Answer (score 1):

Currently symbolizing features with through related record values is not possible. This has been posted on the ArcGIS Ideas page if you want to vote for this feature.
https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/10702